# ValueError: unknown url type in urllib2, though the url is fine if opened in a browser

Tags: python, urllib2, httprequest

Basically, I am trying to download a URL using urllib2 in python.

the code is the following:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('www.tattoo-cover.co.uk')
req.add_header('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

it outputs ValueError and the program crushes for the URL in the example.
When I access the url in a browser, it works fine.

Any ideas how to handle the problem?

**UPDATE:**

thanks for Ben James and sth the problem is detected => add 'http://'

Now the question is refined:
Is it possible to handle such cases automatically with some builtin function or I have to do error handling with subsequent string concatenation?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you enter a URL in a browser without the protocol, it defaults to HTTP. `urllib2` won't make that assumption for you; you need to prefix it with `http://`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use a complete URL including the protocol, not just specify a host name.

The correct URL would be `http://www.tattoo-cover.co.uk/`.

Comment: Yes, sth, good observation! So the follow up question: is it possible to convert bad urls to acceptable by urllib2 with some builtin function or I have to do error handling with string manipulation (by concatenating 'http://' + string + '/') myself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `urlparse` from `urllib` (Python 3) to check the presence of an addressing scheme (http, https, ftp) and concatenate the scheme in case it is not present:

```
In [1]: from urllib.parse import urlparse
    ..: 
    ..: url = 'www.myurl.com'
    ..: if not urlparse(url).scheme:
    ..:     url = 'http://' + url
    ..: 
    ..: url
Out[1]: 'http://www.myurl.com'
```

Comment: Really wish `urllib` did this automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the urlparse function for that I think
:

[Python User Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse)