# Python urllib2 ensuring url is well-formed

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2

In [ValueError: unknown url type in urllib2, though the url is fine if opened in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823572/valueerror-unknown-url-type-in-urllib2-though-the-url-is-fine-if-opened-in-a-b), it was pointed out that before calling `opener.open()` you must ensure that the url passed to it is well-formed (ie - has a  "http://" prefix for HTTP urls, "ftp://" for FTP, etc).

The question was refined to ask "Is it possible to handle such cases automatically with some builtin function or I have to do error handling with subsequent string concatenation?"  Or put another way: is there a Python built-in for doing this?

However, this refined question was never answered, hence the re-asking here.  It's easy enough to do myself, but why reinvent the wheel right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python it's quite common to accept and exception instead of checkin the value in advance. So something like this would be perfectly of for me and probably for most python programmers:

```
try:
    opener.open(url)
except ValueError,e:
    # fix url and try again
    # ...
```

But I don't see how you would like to handle urls without prefix automatically. The prefix defines the protocol to be used. If it's not given, how would you "guess" it?

Comment: Fair enough, my actual use case was always doing http URL's so I didn't think that you can't really tell a protocol from a URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default to prepending `http://`, you really need to do this on your own. There is no reason why this should be better than prepending e.g. `gopher:` or `mailto:` or `news:` - there are plenty of protocols.

Just because web-browsers today hide the `http://` prefix from their users doesn't make it obsolete.

Comment: As a follow up, there also must be at least one slash after the host name. So `http://www.google.com` is actually _not_ a proper URL. Either your browser or the web server will redirect you to `http://www.google.com/` silently though.

Comment: Oh, and if you only intend to support `http://` anyway, you can just consider always prepending it unless your url already starts with `http://`.