# installing urlib and beautifulsoup in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am new to python. Wrote a small program to fetch all links in a page. I am using python 2.7, the one that comes with Ubuntu. I used different sources to put the code together, but it seems like I am either missing a library or using the right library for the wrong version of python.

```
import sys
from bs4 import *
import urllib2
import re

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "USAGE:"
    print "Python test.py Your_URL"
else:
        url = sys.argv[1]

html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 421, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 283, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: www.cs.odu.edu
```

I have installed bs4, urlib after python. Still the same error.

sudo apt install python

sudo apt install python-pip

sudo pip install bs4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter a URL in a browser without the protocol, it defaults to HTTP. urllib2 won't make that assumption for you; you need to prefix it with http://.

Duplicated: 
[ValueError: unknown url type in urllib2, though the url is fine if opened in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823572/valueerror-unknown-url-type-in-urllib2-though-the-url-is-fine-if-opened-in-a-b)

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying http or https before your url, it will definitely work.