# Python - Using OpenWeatherMap API Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am currently completing a Python course (first course, so I am a beginner) and am working on a Python script to pull the user's IP Address to find the city and use the OpenWeatherMap API to pull their current weather/temperature.

I have an API key, but the issue is when I initiate the function I created to get the weather information. It says that there is a ValueError: unknown URL type. When I copy the URL and paste it in Chrome, I get the weather information, so I am a bit confused as to why it isn't working. I have been trying to figure this out, as I am sure its a small and easy error, but I just can't point it out.

Code is below:

```
import urllib
from urllib import request
import json
import re

# Get Public IP Address
def get_ip():
    url = 'http://checkip.dyndns.com/'
    data = request.urlopen(url).read()
    IP = data[-29:-16].decode('utf-8')
    return IP

IP = get_ip()

# Get Location
url = 'http://ipinfo.io/' + IP + '/json'
response = request.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)
city = data['city']

# Get Weather
def get_weather(ip_address):
    
    api_key = str('c6cd68a191650e7e4088f67e068f71ce')
    
    response = request.urlopen(f'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}')
    data = json.load(response)
    
    print("Your City : " + city)
    print("Current Weather : " + str(data['main']['temp'] - 273) + "F")
```

When I try to test run it with:

```
get_weather(IP)
```

I get the value error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Orlando&appid=c6cd68a191650e7e4088f67e068f71ce'
```

The main thing I tried was figuring out the url type, which shows "http.client.HTTPResponse" - so maybe that is what's wrong, which seems like it could be correct, but I am not sure.

If there is anything else anyone would need, please let me know.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try using prefix "http://" in `request.urlopen` - Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823572/valueerror-unknown-url-type-in-urllib2-though-the-url-is-fine-if-opened-in-a-b

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you dmitryro.